# state is empty when defining an image

Tags: reactjs, state, jsx

I'm creating an image upload, but when I select the image and put the image properties in a state, the state is empty.

code:

```
export default function UploadImage() {
  const [image, setImage] = React.useState(null);

  function imageSelectedHandle(event) {
    setImage(event.target.files[0]);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <AdvertiserPhoto for="image">
        <div>
          <img src={!me ? noPhoto : verifyPhoto(me.profile_image)} alt="" />
          <IconCam color="white" width="40" height="30" />
        </div>
      </AdvertiserPhoto>
      <input
        type="file"
        id="image"
        name="image"
        style={{ display: "none" }}
        accept="image/jpg"
        onChange={imageSelectedHandle}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: In the code I informed, I created a state and created a function to set the state.
This function I put in the OnChange of the input.
Every time I select an image from my computer, the function is called and I should insert the properties within the state.
However, if I give a console.log in the state, it is empty.

Comment: I see no problem with your code. Where exactly are you checking whether state is empty?

Comment: I gave a console.log in the state, and it appears empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to read the image file to show

Here is a working demo with some changes since I don't have code for other components

https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-glitter-b48w3?file=/src/App.js:129-348

```js
function imageSelectedHandle(event) {
    const [file] = event.target.files;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

   reader.onloadend = function (e) {
    setImage(reader.result)
   }
}
```

Or

```
function imageSelectedHandle(event) {
    const [file] = event.target.files;
    setImage(URL.createObjectURL(file));
}
```

Comment: the second way worked perfectly, using: URL.createObjectURL(file)

Comment: I tested with both ways and it worked with either approach but second is simpler

Comment: in the first way, it was causing an error here, because the URL was too big.